# Redshift - Finding weighted average of

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to calculate the weighted average using the below data

```
project_name, project_type, sales
project_a, type_1, 2
project_a, type_2, 4
project_a, type_3, 6
project_b, type_1, 4
```

Expected output:

```
project_name, project_type, sales, wgt_average
project_a, type_1, 2, 0.17
project_a, type_2, 4, 0.33
project_a, type_3, 6, 0.5
project_b, type_1, 4, 1
```

Given below is the SQL I have in place:

```
select project_name, project_type, count(project_type) * sum(sales) / nullif(count(sales),0)
from table
```

The above SQL given me count by each project_name / project_type. How could I get the weighted average of project_name, project_type combination

Comment: Given the present data/Table, there is just one instance of project_name, project_type combination. In this case, the weighted average would 1.0. However, what you have shown in the wgt_average seems to be a weighted average over just project_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `SUM` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    project_name,
    project_type,
    sales,
    1.0*sales / SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY project_name) As wgt_average
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    project_name,
    project_type;
```

[image: demo of screen capture below]

### Demo

Comment: I guess, the poser of the question is asking for project_name, project_type combination and not just project_name alone. Should this change the 'Partition by' part?

Comment: @Sowmya No, you are reading incorrectly, the partition is only on project name.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you indeed gave what scott martin is asking for the right most column. However, the poser is not sure of which combination as they are asking "How could I get the weighted average of project_name, project_type combination"

Comment: I understand the source of your confusion.